# Installing Maya on Ubuntu, Problems with libraries

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, installation, shared-libraries, maya

For work I have to use Autodesk Maya 2016 and I'm currently trying to install it under Ubuntu 16.04LTS. I tried multiple methods to install it and I think they all fail because of the same reason.
At first I downloaded the files on Autodesk's website and followed the instructions given in the readme-file. As a second method I used the script I found [here](https://gist.github.com/z3ntu/8ed3fd920ebd8651dd87) .
Both give me similar Problems, all related to some libraries (see below). I installed libxt-dev but still no change. I guess I have to change some pathvariables or something like that (I also tried ldconfig)

What do I have to do to make it work?

Below two excerpts from the output when I try to compile/install the software

```
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -Wno-unused -Wno-comment -o .libs/wmldbcreate wmldbcreate.o  ../../lib/Xm/.libs/libXm.so -lXmu -lXt -lSM -lICE -lXext -lXp -lX11 -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/X11R6/lib
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:267: recipe for target 'wmldbcreate' failed
make[2]: *** [wmldbcreate] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/juhe/Downloads/Autodesk_Maya_2016_EN_Linux_64bit/support/openMotif-2.2.3/tools/wml'
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/juhe/Downloads/Autodesk_Maya_2016_EN_Linux_64bit/support/openMotif-2.2.3/tools'
Makefile:168: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

---

*** Warning: This library needs some functionality provided by -lXt.**
 I have the capability to make that library automatically link in when
 **you link to this library.  But I can only do this if you have a
*** shared version of the library, which you do not appear to have.

*** Warning: This library needs some functionality provided by -lSM.**
 I have the capability to make that library automatically link in when
 **you link to this library.  But I can only do this if you have a
*** shared version of the library, which you do not appear to have.

*** Warning: This library needs some functionality provided by -lICE.**
 I have the capability to make that library automatically link in when
 **you link to this library.  But I can only do this if you have a
*** shared version of the library, which you do not appear to have.

*** Warning: This library needs some functionality provided by -lX11.**
 I have the capability to make that library automatically link in when
 **you link to this library.  But I can only do this if you have a**
 shared version of the library, which you do not appear to have.
 **The inter-library dependencies that have been dropped here will be
*** automatically added whenever a program is linked with this library

Comment: did you tired the dev pack too incase ? sudo apt-get install libx11-dev:i386 libx11-dev

Comment: yes, i installed those packages as well, but no change...